# var $1 = document.getElementById("any"); works only after executing it twice in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I was trying some basic code when I went through this on Chrome Developers Tools console:

[image]

The language specification says that you can declare a variable starting with a letter, $ or _.

So, why is this happening? Is it just a bug or does it have some other justification?
  **Why it doesn't work the first time but works when re-assigning?**

EDIT:

I received comments about $1 to $4 been reserved identifiers, but I still don't get why it get assigned exactly the second time (instead of the first time or never being assigned)

Comment: maybe $0-4 definition is interfering, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#0-4

Comment: It's a reserved identifier for Chrome DevTools.

Comment: @shakib why dont u add your comment as answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the [devtools documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#0-4)

> Dev Tools remembers the last five DOM elements (or JavaScript heap
> objects) that you've selected in the tab (or Profiles panel). It makes
> those objects available as $0, $1, $2, $3, and $4. $0 returns the most
> recently selected element or JavaScript object, $1 returns the second
> most recently selected one, and so on.

these reserved identifiers will act differently from other regular identifiers in console.

hope this helps.